# Исключить повтор элементов в сортировке итерационным методом LISP

Tags: сортировка, lisp, повторы

Не удается исключить повторы из списка. Например, при вызове `(sortlist '(5 5 9 7 7 6))` выдается результат `(9 7 7 6 5 5)`. Какая функция позволит исключить повторы?

```
(defun sortlist (x &aux res i j ci cj n)
  (setq res (copy x))
  (setq n (length res))
  (dotimes (i n res)
    (progn
       (dotimes (j n t)
          (progn
             (setq ci (getel res (+ 1 i)))
             (setq cj (getel res (+ 1 j)))    
             (when (> ci cj) (putel res (+ 1 j) ci)
                             (putel res (+ 1 i) cj)))))))
```

Comment: если вы сортируете набор значений, в которых есть повторяющиеся значения, то функция сортировки не должна их убирать.

Comment: после сортировки удаляйте повторяющиеся значения и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так: сначала сортируете обычной сортировкой, а затем убираете совпадения:

```
(defun setof (x &optional (r nil))
(cond ((null x) r)
      ((member (car x) r) (setof (cdr x) r))
      (t (setof (cdr x) (append r (list (car x)))))))

==> setof

(setof '(1 2 3 1 2))

==> (1 2 3)
```

**Бонус: ссылка -> http://www.cyberforum.ru/lisp/thread702099.html**